# Notepad++ macro to remove lines within specific range

Tags: macros, notepad++

I have a file with some raw data like this:

```
RMR,IV,0000771702159,PO,189.63,193.5,3.87
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,543908537
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742064345
DTM,097,20170130
RMR,IV,0000771702454,PO,202.5,202.5
REF,DP,00064
REF,MR,0020
REF,PO,5654748341
REF,MC,936705865
REF,19,18
REF,ST,0605388000255
DTM,097,20170302
RMR,IV,0000771702644,PO,36.26,37,0.74
REF,DP,00090
REF,MC,505304198
REF,19,26
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
RMR,IV,0000771702645,PO,107.31,109.5,2.19
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,505303606
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
```

What I am looking to do is remove any "block" of data that contains the line "REF,DP,00064" within the block
Each block of text begins with a line that starts with RMR and ends with a line that begins with DTM

So I would like to end up removing the section between the lines below:

```
RMR,IV,0000771702159,PO,189.63,193.5,3.87
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,543908537
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742064345
DTM,097,20170130
-----------------------------------------
RMR,IV,0000771702454,PO,202.5,202.5
REF,DP,00064
REF,MR,0020
REF,PO,5654748341
REF,MC,936705865
REF,19,18
REF,ST,0605388000255
DTM,097,20170302
-----------------------------------------
RMR,IV,0000771702644,PO,36.26,37,0.74
REF,DP,00090
REF,MC,505304198
REF,19,26
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
RMR,IV,0000771702645,PO,107.31,109.5,2.19
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,505303606
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
```

And final result should be:

```
RMR,IV,0000771702159,PO,189.63,193.5,3.87
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,543908537
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742064345
DTM,097,20170130
RMR,IV,0000771702644,PO,36.26,37,0.74
REF,DP,00090
REF,MC,505304198
REF,19,26
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
RMR,IV,0000771702645,PO,107.31,109.5,2.19
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,505303606
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
```

Ive searched and found how to remove if what im searching for is at the beginning but in  my case its in the middle

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No needs for a macro, you could do it with a single regex.

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^RMR(?:(?!DTM).)*\RREF,DP,00064\R(?:(?!DTM).)*DTM.+?\R`
- Replace with: `EMPTY`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

Check `Regular expression` and `. matches newline`

**Explanation:**

```
^               : begining of line
RMR             : literally RMR
(?:             : begin non capture group
  (?!DTM)       : negative lookahead, make sure we don't have DTM
  .             : any character
)*              : non capture group repeated 0 or more times
\R              : any kind of linebreak
REF,DP,00064\R  : literally REF,DP,00064 followed by a line break
(?:(?!DTM).)*   : same as above
DTM.+?          : literally DTM followed 1 or more charcaters non greedy
\R              : any kind of linebreak
```

**Result for given example:**

```
RMR,IV,0000771702159,PO,189.63,193.5,3.87
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,543908537
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742064345
DTM,097,20170130
RMR,IV,0000771702644,PO,36.26,37,0.74
REF,DP,00090
REF,MC,505304198
REF,19,26
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
RMR,IV,0000771702645,PO,107.31,109.5,2.19
REF,DP,00081
REF,MC,505303606
REF,19,27
REF,ST,0078742076270
DTM,097,20170322
```

Comment: Wow that worked amazingly! Thank you very much! and thank you for the explanation!

Comment: just so i can learn a bit more, how would the Find: differ if i were to search only some part of that line so instead of searching for REF,DP,00064 I would maybe search for REF,DP,0006 in case there are multiple different ending numbers?

Comment: @jmoreno5: Replace `REF,DP,00064` with `REF,DP,\d+` to accept 1 or more digits.

Comment: Once again you are awesome! Thank you! I will be using this for a very long time and you have just saved me about 2 hours worth of work!